# Python/Pandas dataframe: Finish writing to file when program stops

Tags: python, pandas, file

I am appending data to dataframes in python in a parallel fashion for multiple CSV-files using the to_csv() function for pandas dataframes.

However when I stop the program while it runs, some files are completely emptied.
When I stop the program unexpectedly, I want python to either finish writing to the file or leave it as it is.

Do you know how to implement this?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Maybe wrap your code in a `try-except-KeyboardInterrupt` which then finishes off the writing

Answer (score 0):

```
csv.flush()
csv.close()
```

The flush() method in Python file handling clears the internal buffer of the file. In Python, files are automatically flushed while closing them. However, a programmer can flush a file before closing it by using the flush() method.